# Localization support in JSR validation API for messages upon failed validation

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation, jsr

I am using spring 3.0.2 for developing a simple web based application like twitter. My server side validations are going good with JSR validation API, but i can't find any ways to internationalized messages in JSR validation API upon failed validation.

I am using following annotation on my model class **Spitter.java** representing a user in application.

> public class Spitter implements Serializable{
>
> ```
> private Long id;
>
>
> @Size(min=8, max=15, message="some msg..")
> @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", message="some msg..")
> private String username;
>
> @Size(min=8, max=15, message="some msg..")
> private String password;
>
> @Size(min=3, max=15, message="some msg..")
> private String name;
>
> @Pattern(regexp="^$",message="some msg..")
> private String email;
>
> @NotNull(message="some msg..")
> @NumberFormat(style= NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER)
> @Min(value=14, message="some msg..")
> @Max(value=99, message="some msg..")
> private Integer age;
>
> //getter setter not shown
>
> }
> ```

I have checked JSR Validation API for localization support upon failed validations, but unable to find the same.

Is there any way i can acheive internationalization.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a ValidationMessages.properties file in your classpath with the approrpriately customized messages. You an either override the current set of messages, say for eg:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=may not be null
```

or if you want to use your own custom message:

```
   @NotNull(message="{custom.message}")
```

an entry for which should be present in the ValidationMessages.properties file.

This information is present in section 4.3.1.1. of JSR 303 specs